# How to detect pre-requisites / co-requisites in GIT?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a simple question in GIT

## Question 1

For example files  (a) 'one.c' (b)  'two.c' and (c)  'three.c' were changed as part of a bug fix

Lets assume files (a) and (b) were committed.  However file (c) was not added / committed by mistake

Prior doing a build using GIT, how build person can determine the pre-requisite / co-requisite of a bug fix?

Pre-requisite / Co-requisite example:  File (c) must be committed (or) needed for building (a) and (b).

Note:  Detecting pre-requisite / co-requisite in CMVC is possible due to its design

## Question 2

In GIT how build person can avoid packaging 'higher version' of file when its 'lower version' was not packaged

Example:  File 'a.c' was changed as part of

Project 'A' (a.c - ver 1.2) 
Project 'B' (a.c - ver 1.3)

But situation demands 'Project B' to be built first.  How this can be avoided prior doing build?

Answer (score 0):

Git is relatively content agnostic, so it does not provide inter-file dependency management, only versioning.

Whatever dependency metadata you had with [IBM Configuration Management Version Control (CMVC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Configuration_Management_Version_Control_%28CMVC%29) is likely to *not* be present in Git.

Comment: I edited my question.  Please can you respond or edit your response

Comment: @SathishKumar The answer stands.

Answer (score 0):

As answer to you by @VonC- git doesn't care about the content of the file, its simply crate "snapshot" of your `index` (all the content which you wish to commit) so you cant trace something like this:

> Project 'A' (a.c - ver 1.2) Project 'B' (a.c - ver 1.3)

You can have the full snapshot of the commits in each repository.

Here you can see the difference between delta to snapshot.

To make it simply, its a bit different in git (patches, heuristics) but to make a long story short, delta store the "delta" between files while git simply take a **"full snapshot"** of your content "regardless" of the changes.

---

[image]